# Why do I get an "exec format" error?

Tags: debian, systemd

I am getting "exec format error" from a systemd service on Debian 8.

This is my service unit file.

```
[Unit]
Description=testele
After=sinusbot9.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/runboti.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

This is the /home/runboti.sh script.

```
rm -fr /tmp/.sinusbot.lock
rm -fr /tmp/.X11-unix/X40
rm -fr /tmp/.sinusbot.lock
rm -fr /tmp/.X11-unix/X40
echo Files removed and starting bots sinusbot-sinusbot9
service sinusbot start
echo service sinusbot  started
rm -fr /tmp/.sinusbot.lock
rm -fr /tmp/.X11-unix/X40
sleep 5
service sinusbot1 start
echo service sinusbot1 started
rm -fr /tmp/.sinusbot.lock
rm -fr /tmp/.X11-unix/X40
sleep 5
service sinusbot2 start
echo service sinusbot1 started
rm -fr /tmp/.sinusbot.lock
rm -fr /tmp/.X11-unix/X40
sleep 5
service sinusbot3 start
echo service sinusbot3 started
rm -fr /tmp/.sinusbot.lock
rm -fr /tmp/.X11-unix/X40
sleep 5
service sinusbot5 start
echo service sinusbot4 started
rm -fr /tmp/.sinusbot.lock
rm -fr /tmp/.X11-unix/X40
sleep 5
service sinusbot6 start
echo service sinusbot6 started
rm -fr /tmp/.sinusbot.lock
rm -fr /tmp/.X11-unix/X40
sleep 5
service sinusbot7 start
echo service sinusbot7 started
rm -fr /tmp/.sinusbot.lock
sleep 5
service sinusbot8 start
echo service sinusbot8 started
rm -fr /tmp/.sinusbot.lock
rm -fr /tmp/.X11-unix/X40
sleep 5
service sinusbot9 start
echo service sinusbot9 started
rm -fr /tmp/.sinusbot.lock
rm -fr /tmp/.X11-unix/X40
echo All bots is started.
```

I have tried `chmod 777`, `chmod 664`, and various other permutations to no avail.  I haven't found an answer from searching the WWW, either.

What is systemd complaining about and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 19):

You need to add a shebang at the start of your script so the kernel knows how to run it:

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -fr /tmp/.sinusbot.lock
…
```